# convert min(min(r, g), b) from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, min

i have code in matlab like this :

```
r = [10 30 23 50 27; 99 21 38 44 62; 90 22 64 12 56];
g = [92 74 91 37 33; 14 82 44 22 49; 88 10 98 74 33];
b = [73 22 94 18 34; 88 37 29 12 30; 79 39 48 95 24];

result = min(min(r, g), b);
```

the result is get the small value between r/g/b, like below :

[image: result]

i try in python using function min(), but it get error : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'min'

```
rgb = cv2.normalize(temp_rgb.astype('float'), None, 0.0, 1.0, 
cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
r = rgb[:, :, 0]
g = rgb[:, :, 1]
b = rgb[:, :, 2]
result = ((r, g).min(),b).min()
```

maybe there is way in python to get result like in matlab? thankyou

Comment: could you post your complete python code? are you using numpy to create the matrices?

Comment: not knowing matlab, is your data a set of three lists of tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.array()` and `numpy.min()` as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# R, G, B data
r = np.array([[10, 30, 23, 50, 27],
              [99, 21, 38, 44, 62],
              [90, 22, 64, 12, 56]])

g = np.array([[92, 74, 91, 37, 33],
              [14, 82, 44, 22, 49],
              [88, 10, 98, 74, 33]])

b = np.array([[73, 22, 94, 18, 34],
              [88, 37, 29, 12, 30],
              [79, 39, 48, 95, 24]])

# Result
result = np.min(np.array([r, g, b]), axis=0)
print(result)
```

The result is a `numpy` array:

```
[[10 22 23 18 27]
 [14 21 29 12 30]
 [79 10 48 12 24]]
```